# asp.net site slow after short wait

Tags: asp.net

I managed a ASP.NET intranet site that use Integrated Windows authentication.  It is deployed in many different countries for the staff in those countries.  This week I have deployed to three countries that have slow connections to the rest of the internet.  That said, the local network here is quite quick.

The site is relatively quick when a user continually make requests (clicks) to the server.  But if the user in inactive for between one or two minutes, the next request is very slow.  After which the request are quick again until there is a minute pause between requests.

What could cause this?

Also, I was wondering if the Integrated Windows Domain logging could affect the initial load time of pages.  Does it query the active directory server or whatever?